# "register_argc_argv = On" in php.ini doesn't apply

Tags: php, apache2, argv, argc

I tried several things and restarted Apache2 each time without any success.

In `phpinfo()`, register_argc_argv stays "off".

I use Ubuntu 14.04.3 64bits, Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.9.

I tried those:

```
register_argc_argv = On
register_argc_argv = True
register_argc_argv: On
register_argc_argv: True
```

In /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.

Comment: I think you will get more answers if you write in english.

Comment: You might have to tell the OP that in French @Tupac

Comment: SVP ecrire votre question en anglais, merci. *How's that Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: Je pense que vous allez avoir des réponses plus et mieux si vous écrivez en anglais. Google translate @JayBlanchard haha

Comment: @Tupac Google "tried". Not perfect, stuff gets lost in translation. Close though ;-)

Comment: More like *Je crois que vous allez avoir des (meilleures) réponses si vous écrivez votre question en anglais.* @Tupac *et voilà* - or *.... si vous étiez pour écrire....* is better grammar. ;-) (si vous étiez pour écrire => if you were to write...)

Comment: (hihi "si vous étiez pour écrire" is not better grammar, it doesn't mean anything in French. I guess you meant "si vous écriviez". Other translations here are close enough and can be understood by a French speaking person though. :) )

Comment: @caCtus It is better grammar and a better sentence. I take it you had high marks in French; es-tu francophone? ;-) Edit: *"it doesn't mean anything in French"* huh?! dafuq? lol

Comment: I'm French and I can assure you that "si vous étiez pour écrire" doesn't mean anything at all. :D Without the context I wouldn't have understood what you tried to say. ^^ (I guess I do the same when I speak/write in English sometimes.)

Comment: @caCtus whatever you say. *"si vous étiez pour écrire"* - Translation: *"if you were to write"*. Mama said so ;-) je sais cosser ch'parle icite viarge! lol - that's called "parler le jouale".

Comment: @caCtus Sort of like *"An Englishman in New York"*? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d27gTrPPAyk

Comment: @Fred-ii- Maybe we can use it in Quebec French, I never heard this form and didn't know it existed. :) Quebec French sometimes looks like translated English. Next time I'll ask on http://french.stackexchange.com/ !

Comment: @caCtus I guess it's a *poh-tay-toe, poh-tah-toe* type of thing. I'll play the *"I'll blame it on the teachers"* card ;-) I speak a few francophone dialects myself which Google's gonna have a heckuva time translating. Elmer Fudd won't help neither. You're a good sport, *cheers*

Comment: I asked other question in english in the past.... I know this website is in english... I just got confused this time because I have many things in my mind these days... does that really deserve a downvote?

Answer (score 5):

Found out:

```
register_argc_argv = On On
```

Comment: On peu bin dire *salut la visite* asteur! ;-)